# Is there a way to replace the last N letters of words longer than X digits?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Does anyone know how can I replace the last N letters of words longer than X digits?
I'm using this code

```
text = re.sub("[A-ZÀ-ÖØ-Ýà-öø-ÿa-z][A-ZÀ-ÖØ-Ýà-öø-ÿa-z]{7,}", "[\g<0>]", text)
```

This is an example output string of what I'm getting now.

```
253.  Ficam [revogadas] a Lei nº 1.711, de 28 de outubro de 1952, e [respectiva] [legislação] [complementar], bem como as demais [disposições] em [contrário].
```

It puts a [] around words that are greater than 7 letters.
However, I just need to wrap the last letter, not the whole word. Does anyone know how to achieve this?
This is my expected output:

```
253.  Ficam revogada[s] a Lei nº 1.711, de 28 de outubro de 1952, e respectiv[a] legislaçã[o] complement[r], bem como as demais disposiçõe[s] em contrári[o].
```

Comment: Another idea is to use a lookbehind, e.g. [`(?u)(?<=[^\W\d_]{7})[^\W\d_]\b`](https://regex101.com/r/0RRWkn/2) but it's less efficient than capturing groups. If you want to match only letters and need a short, use [`[^\W\d_]`](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-interesting-character-classes.html#obnoxious)

Comment: This works! Thanks a lot. May I also ask if you have any idea on how to expand it to more letters? (e.g. `revogad[as]` > `revoga[das]`, etc)

Comment: Add a quantifier like [in this demo](https://regex101.com/r/MDX6GJ/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex for search:

```
(\b\w{6,})(\w)
```

And use: `\1[\2]` for replacement.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/r9jyl5/1)

**Code:**

```py
import re
text = '253.  Ficam revogadas a Lei nº 1.711, de 28 de outubro de 1952, e respectiva legislação complementar, bem como as demais disposições em contrário.'

print (re.sub(r'(\b\w{6,})(\w)', r'\1[\2]', text))
```

**Output:**

> `253.  Ficam revogada[s] a Lei nº 1.711, de 28 de outubr[o] de 1952, e respectiv[a] legislaçã[o] complementa[r], bem como as demais disposiçõe[s] em contrári[o].`

**RegEx Details:**

- `(\b\w{6,})`: Match word boundary followed by 6+ word characters in capture group #1
- `(\w)`: Match last word in capture group #2
- `\1[\2]`: Replacement to put first capture group followed by last word wrapped in `[.]`

Comment: Wow, I just tested and it actually works. Thanks a lot! May I ask what `\1[\2]` does?

Comment: I have placed explanation in my answer. `\N` is back-reference of capture group #N